# Splice Onto Arcane - Rulings

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was wondering what happens to the cards once they are revealed using the Splice Onto Arcane ability?

Do they go to the graveyard once spliced?

Or do they stay in your hand?

With this said and considering the spells are all cast at instant speed, if they stay in your hand, what mechanic stops them from being spliced yet again onto another spell? or is this just a ruling so that people can't place infinite copies of the spells effects onto the initial spell (say with an infinite manna combo)?

> You reveal all cards you intend to splice at the same time. Each individual card can be spliced only once onto any one spell.

The above ruling does not give me much context... is this during any one turn? 
If so does this mean I can reveal it next turn and splice again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Do they go to the graveyard once spliced?

They don't, as nothing says they do.

> Or do they stay in your hand?

Yes, as nothing says they leave it.

> what mechanic stops them from being spliced yet again onto another spell?

Nothing stops them, but the splice cost limits them.

> > You reveal all cards you intend to splice at the same time. Each individual card can be spliced only once onto any one spell.
>
> The above ruling does not give me much context... is this during any one turn? If so does this mean I can reveal it next turn and splice again?

It's a limit per spell. You can only cast a spell once and you only get one opportunity to apply any "as you play a spell" effects. This includes splicing.
If you would retrieve the card that represented that spell and cast it again, it will be a different spell with the same name and you could again apply any "as you play a spell" effects to it.

You can splice a given card onto something any number of times per turn, as long as you provide a new spell for each splicing and as long as you're able to pay the splice cost.

Comment: Ah so essentially, revealing the card can only happen once per spell that was cast and once per card with splice? So it would be impossible to reveal a card and pay its splice cost an infinite amount of times with a manna combo on a single spell that was cast?

Comment: @ThunderToes Yes, each splice card in your hand gives you only a single opportunity to improve each relevant spell.